# Corret way to add Sentry to Flutter

Tags: flutter, sentry

From https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting,

```
runZoned<Future<void>>(() async {
  runApp(CrashyApp());
}, onError: (error, stackTrace) {
  // Whenever an error occurs, call the `_reportError` function. This sends
  // Dart errors to the dev console or Sentry depending on the environment.
  _reportError(error, stackTrace);
});
```

But My IDE said `onError` is decprecated.

[image]

What's the proper way to fix this? I can't any example on runZonedGuarded.

Answer (score 5):

This is the setup that worked for me:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final sentry = Sentry.SentryClient(Sentry.SentryOptions(dsn: '[Add dsn URI here]'));

  runZonedGuarded(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
      sentry.captureException(
        errorDetails.exception,
        stackTrace: errorDetails.stack,
      );
    };

    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    sentry.captureException(
      error,
      stackTrace: stackTrace,
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it [became obsolete](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40681) on Flutter 1.17.0 [(It's a breaking change from Dart 2.8)](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-8-7750918db0a). You could something like this:

```dart
runZonedGuarded(() {
  runApp(CrashyApp());
}, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
  // Whenever an error occurs, call the `_reportError` function. This sends
  // Dart errors to the dev console or Sentry depending on the environment.
  _reportError(error, stackTrace);
});
```